# ! LaTeX Error: File `import.sty' not found

Tags: packages

I'm importing the following packages in my LaTeX document

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

All of them are working except from `import`, `minted` and `biblatex`. Why is that? Do I have to install something?

I edit the document in IntelliJ but run it using my the `pdflatex main-tex-file-name.tex` command.

Comment: Which latex distribution do you use? Texlive or miktex?

Comment: TeX Live (`pdflatex --version` returns `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)`)

Comment: You should be able to install missing packages from the command line via e.g. `tlmgr install import`

Comment: That fixed the problem with the import- and biblatex-package. Thank you! However, I'm still not able to install the minted package. When I run `tlmgr install minted` I get the message `! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.`. If I try to install that package using `tlmgr install pygmentize` I get another error `package pygmentize not present in repository.`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: `pygmentize` is not a latex package, but something from python. Use whatever python package manger you us to install python things.

Comment: (also when you have everything installed and want to compile your document, you will have to use `pdflatex --shell-escape main-tex-file-name` to allow minted to call python which then will do the code highlighting)